# Webdriver and Fluentwait

Tags: selenium

Webdriver wait class extends Fluent wait, hence it(webdriver wait) has all feature like polling the page, ignoring exception and others of fluent wait. Hence is there any specific condition in which we would use fluent wait?

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverWait` is nothing but a specialised case of `FluentWait<T>` where the type is `WebDriver`. So if you want to wait for an event to occur on a driver instance it should be used instead of `FluentWait`. It reduces some keystrokes :)

Within the context of selenium other object we work with is `WebElement`. If you are looking to wait for an event to occur on a element, using `FluentWait` is a better option.

For example:

```
FluentWait<WebElement> wait = new FluentWait<WebElement>(element).withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.until(new Predicate<WebElement>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(WebElement arg0) {
        return arg0.isEnabled();
    }
});
```

You can use the `Function` variant, for example, to wait for a text on a button to change.